# Inner Join table with a maximum date

Tags: mysql

Please help me.

I have 2 table **Users** and **Diseaselogs**

- 1 user has many diseaselogs

I want to select all users and each user must be field date in diseaselogs is max

Data example

- Users

```
id |   name    | age      
1  |   Nam     |  21    
2  |   Thao    |  23   
3  |   An      |  19
```

- Diseaselogs

```
id |   logType    | userId |     date
1  |  positive    |  1     |  2021-06-21
2  |  negative    |  2     |  2021-06-22
3  |   pending    |  1     |  2021-06-24
4  |  negative    |  1     |  2021-06-26
5  |  negative    |  2     |  2021-06-21
6  |   pending    |  3     |  2021-06-23
7  |  negative    |  1     |  2021-06-24
8  |  negative    |  2     |  2021-06-25
9  |   pending    |  3     |  2021-06-28
```

- Expect output

```
id   |  name | logId   |   logType    |   date
1    |  Nam  |   4     |  negative    |  2021-06-26
2    |  Thao |   8     |  negative    |  2021-06-25
3    |  An   |   9     |   pending    |  2021-06-28
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ROW_NUMBER() doesn't support lower version of mysql i.e 5.7 to downwords. So I've tried here alternatives of ROW_NUMBER().

```
-- MySQL (V 5.6)
SELECT u.id, u.name, tmp.logId, tmp.logType, tmp.date
FROM users u
INNER JOIN (SELECT @row_no := IF(@prev_val = t.userId, @row_no + 1, 1) AS row_number
                 , @prev_val := t.userId AS userId
                 , t.date
                 , t.logType
                 , t.id AS logId
            FROM Diseaselogs t,
            (SELECT @row_no := 0) x,
            (SELECT @prev_val := '') y
            ORDER BY t.userId, t.date DESC ) tmp
        ON u.id = tmp.userId
       AND tmp.row_number = 1;
```

Please check url http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/741b96/16

Also if your MySQL version is 5.8 then you can apply the below query where row_number() is used.

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, tmp.logId, tmp.logType, tmp.date
FROM users u
INNER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY date DESC) row_number
                 , userId
                 , date
                 , logType
                 , id AS logId
            FROM Diseaselogs ) tmp
        ON u.id = tmp.userId
       AND tmp.row_number = 1;
```

Comment: I use MySQL version 5.7, This solution ok

Answer (score 0):

in mysql 8 you can use `ROW_NUMBER` and an `INNER JOIN`

in prior versions you need to use another method for rownumber

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE Diseaselogs (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `logType` VARCHAR(8),
  `userId` INTEGER,
  `date` VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO Diseaselogs
  (`id`, `logType`, `userId`, `date`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'positive', '1', '2021-06-21'),
  ('2', 'negative', '2', '2021-06-22'),
  ('3', 'pending', '1', '2021-06-24'),
  ('4', 'negative', '1', '2021-06-26'),
  ('5', 'negative', '2', '2021-06-21'),
  ('6', 'pending', '3', '2021-06-23'),
  ('7', 'negative', '1', '2021-06-24'),
  ('8', 'negative', '2', '2021-06-25'),
  ('9', 'pending', '3', '2021-06-28');

CREATE TABLE users (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `name` VARCHAR(4),
  `age` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO users
  (`id`, `name`, `age`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Nam', '21'),
  ('2', 'Thao', '23'),
  ('3', 'An', '19');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
 u.id, `name`, t1.id,`logType`, `date`
FROM
(SELECT
id,`logType`, `userId`, `date`
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `userId` ORDER BY `date` DESC) rn
FROM
Diseaselogs) t1 
INNER JOIN users u ON t1.userId = u.id
 WHERE rn = 1;
```

| id | name | id | logType | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nam | 4 | negative | 2021-06-26 |
| 2 | Thao | 8 | negative | 2021-06-25 |
| 3 | An | 9 | pending | 2021-06-28 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/exfkgCJpH9X4ped4S2PGpj/2)

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE Diseaselogs (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `logType` VARCHAR(8),
  `userId` INTEGER,
  `date` VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO Diseaselogs
  (`id`, `logType`, `userId`, `date`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'positive', '1', '2021-06-21'),
  ('2', 'negative', '2', '2021-06-22'),
  ('3', 'pending', '1', '2021-06-24'),
  ('4', 'negative', '1', '2021-06-26'),
  ('5', 'negative', '2', '2021-06-21'),
  ('6', 'pending', '3', '2021-06-23'),
  ('7', 'negative', '1', '2021-06-24'),
  ('8', 'negative', '2', '2021-06-25'),
  ('9', 'pending', '3', '2021-06-28');

CREATE TABLE users (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `name` VARCHAR(4),
  `age` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO users
  (`id`, `name`, `age`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Nam', '21'),
  ('2', 'Thao', '23'),
  ('3', 'An', '19');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
 u.id, `name`, `age`,`logType`, `date`
FROM
(SELECT
`logType`, `userId`, `date`
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `userId` ORDER BY `date` DESC) rn
FROM
Diseaselogs) t1 
INNER JOIN users u ON t1.userId = u.id
 WHERE rn = 1;
```

| id | name | age | logType | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nam | 21 | negative | 2021-06-26 |
| 2 | Thao | 23 | negative | 2021-06-25 |
| 3 | An | 19 | pending | 2021-06-28 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/exfkgCJpH9X4ped4S2PGpj/2)