# Get Details of all customers last inserted values

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get last inserted data of each customer.i am using the given query

```
SELECT id,
       customer,
       value 
FROM customer
GROUP BY customer 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

The table i have is below

| id | customer | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 1.6 |
| 2 | abc | 2.7 |
| 3 | aaa | 8.6 |
| 4 | acd | 7.5 |
| 5 | abc | 1.6 |

From the above table i want the result like this:

| id | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | aaa | 8.6 |
| 5 | abc | 1.6 |
| 4 | acd | 7.5 |

Comment: which version of mySQL do u use? Use ROW_NUMBER() if your version is 5.8.

Comment: @RahulBiswas Using MYSQL 5.7

Comment: Please check my answer from this url and apply according to your need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68489020/inner-join-table-with-a-maximum-date/68490027#68490027     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68756782/select-where-last-row-has-a-condition-true-in-a-field/68756872#68756872

Comment: @AnjuLS `abc` max value should be 2.7 not 1.6 in your expected result. Check my answer if it helps

Comment: it should be 1.6 since its id is greater @ErgestBasha

Comment: @AliFidanli you are right, i thought it needed the max value for customer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `id`, customer, `value`
  from customer c
 where c.`id` = (select max(cc.id) from customer cc where cc.`customer` = c.`customer`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
    SELECT id,
       customer,
       `value` 
FROM customer 
WHERE (customer,id) in 
        (
          SELECT    customer , 
                    max(`id`) as id 
          FROM customer 
          GROUP BY customer 
         ) ;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qff694udysNgqbyJyFcDzn/5